# Does tvOS have any UIViewController subclasses I can use instead of replicating standard functionality?

Tags: ios, uikit, tvos, apple-tv

I've started developing for tvOS recently, and discovered that while TVML isn't ideal for our use case, we'd still like to display a number of screens that display the same types of content as I've seen in existing Apple apps, and which I know can be created with TVML.

As an example, I want to display a page of terms, the same way that the Apple TV displays information as a scrollable page of text.

[image]

I could do this custom, where I place my own textView on a UIViewController, and setup the width and positioning myself. But it's scenarios like this, where I'm wondering if there's some already existing standard control for it, such as a UIViewController subclass already setup for displaying Terms? Is there a set of these I could be looking at?

Comment: BTW, you can see a full list of view controllers on [the view controller docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/tvos/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/swift/cl/c:objc(cs)UIViewController) under "Inherits From"

Comment: Thanks you for this question. I was asking myself the same but for different screens and UI components. I want a movie detail screen like the one Apple created for the iTunes movie app. I was also looking for a expandable "show more" Label, like the one Apple uses on a movie detail screen. But it seems that there are no templates available.

Comment: Why wouldn't you use TVML templates? https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/tvos/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/ATV_Template_Guide/TextboxTemplate.html

Comment: @EugeneZhenyaGordin Because our app needs some custom features, more complicated than using TVML would allow. I'm not sure there's a way to implement TVML partially.

Comment: there is a way to do both, it's called bridging.

Answer (score 0):

UIAlertController should solve what you're looking for. You configure the text, buttons, and then present it.

More info in the docs:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIAlertController_class/